# sum if containing a certain value in a column

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a formula something like sumif.
Here is the example.

```
1 A1 289LOT9172
2 A2 289LOT9173
3 A3 289LOT9174
4 B1 1000
5 B2 2000
6 B3 3000
7 C1 289
8 C2 289
9 C3 289
```

I need the sum of "B" if "C" contains in "A"

Please help.

Comment: That's not like a `SUMIF`, it is one

Comment: *"Contains an A"* or *"Starts with an A"* ? Using wildcards in formulas can be prone to false positives unless the conditions are explicitly set out.

Comment: Guys, this isnt a free code warehouse! Please show what you have done and tell us the errors you got. Dont just ask for free code!

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this. It's very simple if method but in this case works.
Do you have more then 3 rows of data?

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(C1,A1)),0,B1)+IF(ISERROR(FIND(C2,A2)),0,B2)+IF(ISERROR(FIND(C3,A3)),0,B3)
```